# Do you know a user management project in Java?

Tags: java, open-source, user-management

I'm looking for a lightweight and easy to install user management system made in JAVA. It should use a free Database System (MySQL for example) and handle basic security after logging (access or not with error message). I'm not looking for anything fancy/flexible like SpringSecurity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think [OpenLdap](http://www.openldap.org/) would meet your requirements although not written in java, but which db other then derby is written in java?

[Here](http://www.concentric.net/~adhawan/tutorial/) is a tutorial how you access it using JNDI.

Comment: I would not consider LDAP as a match for "not fancy/flexible".